# SQL efficient solution for mutilple joins (could be 10 joins) on same table (lookup table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

We've implemented a lookup table that contains an ID and a Text field. My table then only consists of the LookupID for different field values. For example...

Table

- TableID, StatusID, TypeID, DocID

Values would look something like this

- 1, 2, 3, 4

LookupTable

- LookupID, Text

Values would look something like this

- 1, SomeValue
- 2, My Status Text
- 3, My Type Text
- 4, My Document Text

What I need to know is if this is most efficient solution for a query on these tables (creating a sql view of the data with the text displayed instead of the ID)

```
SELECT T.TableID, L1.Text as StatusText, L2.Text as TypeText, L3.Text as DocText
FROM Table T
LEFT JOIN LookupTable L1 on L1.LookupID = T.StatusID
LEFT JOIN LookupTable L2 on L2.LookupID = T.TypeID
LEFT JOIN LookupTable L3 on L3.LookupID = T.DocID
```

... or do subqueries work better for this solution? Something like this.

```
SELECT T.TableID,
  (SELECT L.Text FROM LookupTable L WHERE L.LookupID = T.StatusID) as StatusText,
  (SELECT L.Text FROM LookupTable L WHERE L.LookupID = T.TypeID) as TypeText,
  (SELECT L.Text FROM LookupTable L WHERE L.LookupID = T.DocID) as DocText
FROM Table T
```

... Or is there a better solution? Keep in mind I only joined 3 times for this example and will need to join 10 or more times.

Comment: It's pretty hard to comment on what the best solution is when you've only presented a hypothetical situation. In any event, the idea of using a single "LookupTable" seems like a **really** bad idea. `JOIN`s will also almost always be better than the subquery approach that you have. Beyond that it's hard to comment. The design doesn't pass the smell test, but I can't say when it's just "Table" and "SomeValue", etc.

Comment: Did you test the performance of the two possible queries you provided? I have had cases where the correlated subqueries performed better.

Comment: I built in a MasterXref table one time in an application a LONG time ago and regretted it for the life of that system. It was god awful to work with and the performance was challenging when you ended up hitting the same table over and over and over in queries all over the place. I will NEVER do that again.

Comment: @trincot Tables are too small for really determining perfomance. I may Create a few large tables to see if performance is different between the two.

Comment: @SeanLange What would you suggest doing instead of the one table?

Comment: @TomH I'm sorry I couldn't give a better presented situation. The lookup table was created to give us ease of access to dynamic options. So I can pick from 20 different (lookupIDs) that all pertain to the Status of that item. It was ultimately created by a MS Access guy... (creating lookup tables for drop down lists)

Comment: A separate table for each lookup. It is much easier to code and maintain. You also don't have one single table becoming the busiest table in your system to retrieve human readable display values.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah I don't think this Lookup Table was thought through to what will happen when it has 100's of thousands of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to create separate lookup tables for each separate entity in your database. This gives you better flexibility in the future, should you need to add an additional attribute for a single lookup type (for example, now you need to track state birds for each state, but that certainly won't be relevant for car models). In my experience "generic" database design patterns usually turn out bad. Design with a purpose.

Once you have that, as long as you have the appropriate indexes having multiple `JOIN`s will almost always (if not always) perform better than subqueries:

```
SELECT
    P.person_id,
    S.state_name,
    G.movie_genre_name,
    ...
FROM
    Person P
INNER JOIN [State] S ON S.state_id = P.home_state_id
INNER JOIN Movie_Genre G ON G.movie_genre_id = P.favorite_movie_genre_id
...
```

Also, keep in mind that every list in your system doesn't have to necessarily be a lookup table. Something like gender, for example, can be maintained simply through a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
gender VARCHAR(15) NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Person_Gender CHECK (gender IN ('Male', 'Female', 'Transgender'))
```

or:

```
severity VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Ticket_Severity CHECK (severity IN ('High', 'Medium', 'Low'))
```

This is relevant for lists that are basically just a name. Lists that have items with additional attributes or lists that might change frequently over time should be put into a table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [UNPIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) to break it out?

Comment: I have not. I will look into it.